# Embedding youtube video to Flash project and Resizing it in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs6

Hello i'm trying to embed a youtube video into my flash project using as3.0. So far I've been able to get the video to my frame and play it. But my stage size is 500X500. So I need my video to be width:300 and height:150. I tried changing the video size but that's not worked for me. The video has it's original embedding width and height... So how can I do that?

Here is my code.

```
var player:Object;

var loader:Loader = new Loader();

var context:LoaderContext = new LoaderContext();
context.checkPolicyFile = true;
context.securityDomain = SecurityDomain.currentDomain;
context.applicationDomain = ApplicationDomain.currentDomain;

loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.INIT, onLoaderInit);
Security.allowDomain("www.youtube.com")
loader.load(new URLRequest("http://www.youtube.com/v/yNfkNWfH6aU?version=3"));

function onLoaderInit(event:Event):void {
    addChild(loader);
    loader.content.addEventListener("onReady", onPlayerReady);
    loader.content.addEventListener("onError", onPlayerError);
    loader.content.addEventListener("onStateChange", onPlayerStateChange);
    loader.content.addEventListener("onPlaybackQualityChange", onVideoPlaybackQualityChange);
}

function onPlayerReady(event:Event):void {
    // Event.data contains the event parameter, which is the Player API ID 
    trace("player ready:", Object(event).data);

    // Once this event has been dispatched by the player, we can use
    // cueVideoById, loadVideoById, cueVideoByUrl and loadVideoByUrl
    // to load a particular YouTube video.
    player = loader.content;
    // Set appropriate player dimensions for your application
    player.setSize(300, 150);
    //player.x = stage.width/2; //puts the video horizontally centered
    //player.y = stage.width/2; //puts the video vertically centered
    //player.x=100;
    //player.width=265;
    //player.height=200;
}

function onPlayerError(event:Event):void {
    // Event.data contains the event parameter, which is the error code
    trace("player error:", Object(event).data);
}

function onPlayerStateChange(event:Event):void {
    // Event.data contains the event parameter, which is the new player state
    trace("player state:", Object(event).data);
}

function onVideoPlaybackQualityChange(event:Event):void {
    // Event.data contains the event parameter, which is the new video quality
    trace("video quality:", Object(event).data);
}
```

Comment: Maybe **loader.scaleX = 300/500; loader.scaleY = 150/500;** ?

Comment: not working mate, same result..